# Cannot access registered dataset in AMLS pipeline

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, vnet

I have a service principal for my AMLS workspace that has been granted a storage blob contributor role to ADLS Gen 2. ADLS Gen 2 is behind a vnet, but using the service principal, I was able to register it as a datastore and register a csv file in ADLS Gen 2 as a dataset in my AMLS workspace. I am using azureml.core version 1.16.0

Within my workspace, running

```
data = ws.datasets.get("csv data")
data.take(5).to_pandas_dataframe()
```

works with no issue. I would like to use this csv data as input into an ML pipeline run with a PythonScriptStep with inputs = [data.as_named_input('data')] after running data = ws.datasets.get("csv data"). However, when I run the code

```
run = Run.get_context()
run.input_datasets['data'].to_pandas_dataframe()
```

in my pipeline script, it fails with an error

```
StreamAccessException was caused by AuthenticationException.
'AdlsGen2-ReadHeaders' for '[REDACTED]' on storage failed with status code 'Forbidden' (This request is
not authorized to perform this operation.)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: My hunch is that this error is caused by running on a compute cluster that is not connected to the vnet. However, I'm unable to run *any* ML pipelines on compute that is connected to the vnet (despite being able to do this in the past). I think there may be a larger underlying problem related to this...